# Symfony 2 - use Composer to include vendor libraries not available as packages

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a Symfony 2 application which makes use of a legacy vendor library.  This library is a self-contained folder full of PHP code, which I put into my `vendor` folder and include using Symfony's classloading mechanism, but which is not available anywhere as a Package, and not currently handled using Composer - I have to copy it manually into the `vendor` folder as part of a deployment (`vendor` not being tracked in source control).

How would I bring this legacy library under the control of Composer?  I want to be able to deploy a clean copy of my app, and then use Composer to set up all the libraries it needs, including the legacy one.  I'd like to do this with the minimum of effort - I don't particular want to package anything up unless I have to, ideally I'd like to make the library available at some pre-arranged location outside of the application, and for Composer to pick it up from there.

Comment: Throw it in a private/personal Git repo and [include it in your Composer package from there](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do one of:

- put the library into a repository and add a `composer.json` to it, so you could load it [as a package from a vcs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository)
- put the library into a repository and [configure a package](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) in your project's `composer.json`

In both cases you can configure composer's autoloader if your library follows [one of the supported methods](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload).